# polynomial time reduction from a problem to a NP-complete problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I have problems to solve the following question:
If there are two problems p1 and p2, p2 is NP-complete and there is a polynomial reduction from p1 to p2, then p1 ...
a) is NP-hard but not necessarily NP-complete
b) could be in P, even if P!=NP
c) is NP-complete
d) none of the above
I think c) is correct, but I am not sure and how can I justify ist?

Comment: There are two problems, *p1* and *p2*. *p2* is NP-complete. This tells us absolutely nothing about *p1*. Do you mean to say that there is a reduction from one to the other?

Comment: @Berthur yes, there is a polynomial reduction from p1 to p2

Comment: @marc Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a polynomial-time reduction from *p1* to *p2* it means that if you get an instance of problem *p1*, then you can transform it (in polynomial time) to an instance of problem *p2*. What does that tell us about problem *p1*?

Well, not very much. It means it's decidable, but it doesn't tell us a lot about its time complexity. For all we know, it might be the problem "What is 1+1?".

Had it been the other way around, then it would imply that *p1* is *NP-hard* because otherwise we could solve *p2* in polynomial time by reducing it to *p1* and solving that in polynomial time.

So, since we don't know anything else about *p1*, the answer should be **b)**.